# ansible roles split tasks/main.yml in multiple files

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I want to split my tasks/main.yml into different files in my Ansible role. With *defaults/* and *vars/*, Ansible supports the creation of a *main* directory instead of the *main.yml*, from which all **.yml* files are included. Unfortunately, I can't find anything comparable for tasks. I don't want to enter every yml file in the main.yml again.

So I search for a way to *"auto-include"* all plays in the task-directory.
Does anyone has an idea or example?

Comment: There is no auto-include in tasks. Only explicit *inlcude_tasks* and *import_tasks*. Btw. in what order should the tasks be executed if there were any auto-include?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fileglob](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html) with `include_tasks`, like:

```yaml
include_tasks: '{{item}}'
loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob'  'dir/*.yml' ) }}"
```

See also: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/48866#issuecomment-440432119

Comment: Thank you, that was the way , i was searching for.
At this [link](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/32792) i found a nice implementation.